# Check if site contains duplicate text

Tags: c#, regex

I want to know if site contain specific text duplicated.

I obtain source code by this:

```
public static string getSourceCode(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
    string sourceCode = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Close();
    resp.Close();
    return sourceCode;

}
```

And then I am checking the second group of the Regex expression

```
            try
            {
                sourceCode = Worker.getSourceCode(url);

                Regex r = new Regex("(" + textBox1.Text + ")");

                var m = r.Match(sourceCode);

                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(m.Groups[1].Value);

            }

            catch

            {


            }
```

And it is not working properly. For example my source code contains:

```
exampleexampleexampleXYZ
exampleXYZ
example
exampleXYZ
```

And my function says, that there are only 2 groups of `XYZ`, not 3.

Another example, it there is:

```
exampleXYZ
example
example
example
```

Now it is finding `m.Groups[1].Value` when there should be only `m.Groups[0].Value`. Why?

Comment: So you're asking why your regex matches some substrings and not others, but you figured we could answer that question for you without seeing your actual regex. Would you like us to guess your height and weight as well? By the way, `Groups[0]` is the whole match, regardless of grouping; `Groups[1]` is the first group, if any. [They actually document this stuff, for some reason](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I thought that was clear, that `regex r = new Regex("(" + textBox1.Text + ")");` when `textBox1.Text = "XYZ";`

Comment: You're not batting 1000 on your assumptions today.

Answer (score 2):

I may have misinterpreted your question, but it appears to me that your problem is that you guessed wrong about what [`Match.Groups`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups(v=vs.110).aspx) means.

Consider the following:

```
var re = new Regex("[a-z]([0-9]+)");
var m = re.Match("a1b22c333");
```

What is in `m.Groups`? Your theory -- well no, actually, *my* theory is that your theory is that it's this:

```
{ "1", "22", "333" }
```

That's not what's supposed to be in `m.Groups`. This is what's in `m.Groups`:

```
{ "a1", "1" }
```

That's because `Regex.Match` matches the *first match* only. It returns a `Match` object describing what it found in that one single match. The first item in `Match.Groups` is the *entire match*, irrespective of capturing groups. The remaining items are what the capturing groups matched. A capturing group is defined by a substring of the regex enclosed in unescaped parentheses.

There was one capturing group in my regular expression above:

```
([0-9]+)
```

The first entire match is "a1". The first capturing group matched the sequence of digits following the *uncaptured* character set `[a-z]`.

If you want all the matches at once, call [`Regex.Matches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns [`MatchCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchcollection(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var re = new Regex("[a-z]([0-9]+)");

foreach (var m in re.Matches("a1b22c333")) {
    Console.WriteLine("Match:");
    Console.WriteLine("  full match: " + m.Groups[0].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("  first captured group: " + m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

And you don't need to bother putting parens around your entire regex; all you get then is a single capturing group that's identical to the entire match. No harm in it, but it doesn't add anything.